# Yii2 Trying to get property of non-object error with listView relational model

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I have two tables.

1. students(id,email,password,f_name,l_name,unique_id,create_date,last_update)
2. comments(id,ad_id,commented_user,comment,create_date,last_update)

**table relation**
-> comments.commented_user = students.email

comments class

```
    class Comments extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    //public $commented_user_fName;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'comments';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['comment'], 'string'],
            [['create_date', 'last_update'], 'safe'],
            [['ad_id', 'commented_user'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'ad_id' => 'Ad ID',
            'commented_user' => 'Commented User',
            'comment' => 'Comment',
            'create_date' => 'Create Date',
            'last_update' => 'Last Update',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord){
            $this->commented_user = $_SESSION['login_student_email'];
            $this->create_date = new Expression('NOW()');
        }


        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }

    public function getStudentName(){
        $this->hasOne(Students::className() ,['commented_user' => 'email']);
    }

}
```

My comment Controller Index methord

```
public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        $model = new Comments();
        $model->setAttribute('ad_id',$id);
        $searchModel = new CommentsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(["CommentsSearch"=>['ad_id'=>$id]]);

        return $this->renderAjax('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

I try to get f_name of student table in my ListView

```
<?=
            ListView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'layout' => "{items}",
                'itemView' => 'view',
            ]);
            ?>
```

Item view file code below

```
<a href="#"><?= $model->studentName->f_name ?></a>
```

I got this error

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException 
>   Trying to get property of non-object

on this line `<a href="#"><?= $model->studentName->f_name ?></a>`

What is wrong with my code. Please help me

Comment: you should go through the documentation to know how to access the column names via relation

Answer (score 0):

`.` is concatenation operator, so `$model->studentName.f_name` is not treated as `$model->{studentName.f_name}` but as `{$model->studentName} . f_name`.

You probably need to use `$model->studentName->f_name`.

Comment: {<a href="#"><?= $model->studentName->f_name ?></a> <time><?=$model->create_date ?></time>}

i tried that. I got this error on same line
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Make sure that you have properly defined relation - if `$model->studentName` is null, then you may have database inconsistency or bug in declaration of relation.

Answer (score 0):

You should access to the property as $model->studentName->f_name as with any other Model

Comment: "<a href="#"><?= $model->studentName->f_name ?></a> <time><?=$model->create_date ?></time>"

i tried that. I got this error on same line
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That would happen if the studentName relation is returning a null value. It may have something to do with how the relation is declared. Try changing the relation to: public function getStudentName(){
        $this->hasOne(Students::className() ,['email' => 'commented_user']);
    }